# How to find all the subsets of a collection with duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Write code to find all the combinations of ABB.

The answer should be

```
A

B

AB

BB

ABB
```

[This lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?index=18&list=PLnfg8b9vdpLn9exZweTJx44CII1bYczuk&v=J_odcqzHGqw) shows how to deal with subsets with no duplicates. I can't find an efficient solution online to solve this.

Comment: Did you write a code for solving this issue yourself?

Comment: Suppose for a moment that the multiset contains N elements K times each. Then there are (K+1)^N subsets, and enumerating them is equivalent to enumerating N-digit numbers in base K+1. Now this is straightforward to generalise to N elements that are contained a different number of times each.

Comment: The way I solved it is I sorted every individual record in the result and then put it into a set to get rid of the duplicates. But I think that's inefficient. I was still exploring all those paths in the recursion tree that didn't need to be explored.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively:

```
def subsets(seq):
    lst = list(seq)
    if lst:
        x = lst.pop()
        yield (x,)
        for sst in subsets(lst):
            yield (x,) + sst
        yield from subsets([y for y in lst if y != x])

>>> list(subsets('aab'))
[('b',), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('a',), ('a', 'a')]
```

You can modify the logic to pop the min element if you want the output to be sorted:

```
def subsets(seq):
    lst = list(seq)
    if lst:
        i = min(range(len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)
        x = lst.pop(i)
        yield (x,)
        for sst in subsets(lst):
            yield (x,) + sst
        yield from subsets([y for y in lst if y != x])

>>> list(subsets('ABB'))
[('A',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'B'), ('B',), ('B', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 this is pretty easy with `itertools`

```
import itertools


s = "ABB"

combinations = []

for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
    for combo in set(itertools.permutations(s, i)):
        combinations.append("".join(combo))

for c in combinations:
    print(c)
```

### This outputs:

```
B
A
AB
BB
BA
BAB
ABB
BBA
```

Comment: That's permutation and not sub set. ABB and BBA are the same. Also the aim is to write the underlying algorithm and not use libraries.

Comment: Your output is different from what is requested. Cleaning up duplicates post factum is possible but inefficient.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought by "no duplicates" that you meant  _no **one** element matches another **exactly**_. I also saw nothing in the question that said no external libraries.

Comment: You are right. I thought if I added algorithm to the tags, that would be enough. How should I edit the question to make the intent clearer?

Comment: @Jebby: I guess they want to test the ability of the student to write such an algorithm, not to test how well he knows the existing libraries and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
strin="ABB"
import copy
ans=[]
def appending(index,answer):
    global ans
    if(index<len(strin)):
        answer1=copy.deepcopy(answer)
        answer1.append(strin[index])
        appending(index+1,answer1)
        appending(index+1,answer)
    else:
        if answer not in ans:
            ans.append(answer)
        return
appending(0,[])

for i in ans:
    if i:
        print(''.join(i))
```

i got your output, hope you find it useful

```
ABB
AB
A
BB
B
```